# Sort pandas grouped cols in line

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, numpy

I am working on some machine learning task and I want change each line from "numbered objects" to "sorted by some attrs objects".

For example, I have 5 heroes in 2 teams represented by theirs stats  (dN_%stat% and rN_%stat%), and what I want is to sort heroes in each team by stats numbered 3,4,0,2 so the first one is strongest and so on.

Here is my current code, but it is very slow, so I want to use native pandas objects and operations:

```
def sort_heroes(df):
    for match_id in df.index:
        for team in ['r', 'd']:
            heroes = []
            for n in range(1,6):
                heroes.append(
                    [df.ix[match_id, '%s%s_%s' % (team, n, stat)]
                     for stat in stats])

            heroes.sort(key=lambda x: (x[3], x[4], x[0], x[2]))
            for n in range(1,6):
                for i, stat in enumerate(stats):
                    df.ix[match_id, '%s%s_%s' %
                          (team, n, stat)] = heroes[n - 1][i]
```

Short example with not full but useful data representation:

```
match_id  r1_xp  r1_gold  r2_xp  r2_gold  r3_xp  r3_gold  d1_xp  d1_gold d2_xp d2_gold
1         10     20       100    10       5000   300      0      0       15     5
2         1      1        1000   80       100    13       200    87      311    67
```

What I want is to sort those columns by groups with prefix (rN_ and dN_) firstly by gold then by xp

```
match_id  r1_xp  r1_gold  r2_xp  r2_gold  r3_xp  r3_gold  d1_xp  d1_gold d2_xp d2_gold
1         5000   300      10     20       100    20       15     5       0      0
2         1000   80       100    13       1      1        200    87      311    67
```

Comment: Could you post a short example of how your dataframe is structured?

Comment: What are the rows in your dataframe?

Comment: each row represents info about match where heroes %team%%NUM% take part

Comment: First idea: Split your dataframe into 2 dataframes, one for each group, then split each group into 2 dataframes each containing only either gold or xp, then sort each dataframe rowwise with `df.sort(axis=1)`, then rebuild your original dataframe. However you need to be aware that (as in the example you posted), you lose the information about which hero the values belonged to. I don't know if that is of any concern, though. There's probably a more elegant solution than actually splitting the frames, but this should give you better performance since you are no longer performing loops in python.

Comment: If you iterate over a pandas dataframe always use one of the builtin iterators, that is `iterrows`, `iteritems`, or `itertuples`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.set_index('match_id', inplace=True)
#create MultiIndex  with 3 levels
arr = df.columns.str.extract('([rd])(\d*)_(.*)', expand=True).T.values
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arr)
#reshape df, sorting
df = df.stack([0,1]).reset_index().sort_values(['match_id','level_1','gold','xp'], 
                                                ascending=[True,False,False,False])
print (df)
   match_id level_1 level_2   gold      xp
4         1       r       3  300.0  5000.0
2         1       r       1   20.0    10.0
3         1       r       2   10.0   100.0
1         1       d       2    5.0    15.0
0         1       d       1    0.0     0.0
8         2       r       2   80.0  1000.0
9         2       r       3   13.0   100.0
7         2       r       1    1.0     1.0
5         2       d       1   87.0   200.0
6         2       d       2   67.0   311.0

#asign new values to level 2
df.level_2 = df.groupby(['match_id','level_1']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
#get original shape
df = df.set_index(['match_id','level_1','level_2']).stack().unstack([1,2,3]).astype(int)
df = df.sort_index(level=[0,1,2], ascending=[False, True, False], axis=1)
#Multiindex in columns to column names
df.columns = ['{}{}_{}'.format(x[0], x[1], x[2]) for x in df.columns]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

```
print (df)
   match_id  r1_xp  r1_gold  r2_xp  r2_gold  r3_xp  r3_gold  d1_xp  d1_gold  \
0         1   5000      300     10       20    100       10     15        5   
1         2   1000       80    100       13      1        1    200       87   

   d2_xp  d2_gold  
0      0        0  
1    311       67
```